# Ajax webform: refresh page on a successful submission

Tags: ajax, webforms

I am using the ajax webform, because I don't want the page to be reloaded when the user doesn't enter everything correctly because my form slides in and reloading just causes it to disappear and you would have to navigate back there. When I have ajax-mode enabled, the redirect part works differently, and since the site has only 1 page, it doesn't really do anything, the form doesn't close.

What I want to do it actually refresh the page when the form is submitted with ajax-mode on.

Answer (score 0):

Thus topic has its own issue in the module's issue queue:
[Need to get the redirect message of successful webform submission via ajax with ajax_disable_redirect.module](https://www.drupal.org/node/518970)

There's a patch but nobody tested it. Maintainer is waitinig for some confirmation. If you need it go for it.